# Model appears fine in Texture Mode but white in Render Mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I created an animation, and when I go into texture mode all my mesh textures show up just fine, but when I go into render mode its all white and weird. I'm using Cycles.

Why does this happen?

Final Picture is sun strength.[image]

[image: texture mode]

[image: cycles render view]

Comment: Only guessing here, since not much info to work with. How strong is your sun? You also seem to use a HDRi image that affects lightning, too.

Comment: @metaphor_set I added a picture of the sun strength. It seems to happen no matter what I set it to, even 0.

Comment: What happens when you deactivate the sun?

Comment: @metaphor_set even completely deleting the sun makes nothing change. im thinking maybe theres some post processing settings to blame?